# How to add external non modular jar to java 9 modular application?

Tags: java, gradle, java-9

I have simple java 9 and gradle application. I have added some external dependency to the application. When I try to run gradle task `createFinalAppBundle`, I am getting following error,

```
error: module not found: com.sun.jna
error: module not found: com.sun.jna.platform
```

Below is my module-info.java file

```
module in.abcd.launcher {
    requires com.sun.jna.platform;
    requires com.sun.jna;

    exports in.abcd.launcher;
}
```

Below is my entire gradle.build file

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.9
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.5.1'
    distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-all.zip"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna', version: '5.5.0'
    compile group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna-platform', version: '5.5.0'
}

def jdk = System.getProperty("java.home")
def moduleName = "in.abcd.launcher"
def mainClass = 'in.abcd.launcher.Launcher'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': mainClass,
        )
    }
}

// creates application bundle (executable + runtime)
task javaPackager(type: Exec, dependsOn: assemble) {

    workingDir project.projectDir
    commandLine = [
            'javapackager',
            '-deploy',
            '-nosign',
            '-native', 'image',
            '-outdir', "${buildDir}/distribution",
            '-outfile', project.name,
            '-name', project.name,
            '-appclass', mainClass,
            '-p', "${jdk}/jmods${File.pathSeparator}${buildDir}/libs",
            '--add-modules', moduleName,
            '-m', "$moduleName/$mainClass"
    ]
}

// removes bloated runtime created by javapackager
task cleanPackagerRuntime(dependsOn: javaPackager) {
    doLast() {
        File runtimeFile = new File("${buildDir}/distribution/${project.name}/runtime")
        runtimeFile.deleteDir()
        System.out.println("deleting bloated runtime in " + runtimeFile)
    }
}

// creates a replacement runtime via jlink command (much smaller than jpackager)
task createFinalAppBundle(type: Exec, dependsOn: [cleanPackagerRuntime]) {

    workingDir project.projectDir
    commandLine = [
            'jlink',
            '-p', "${jdk}/jmods${File.pathSeparator}${buildDir}/libs",
            '--add-modules', moduleName,
            '--strip-debug',
            '--no-header-files',
            '--no-man-pages',
            '--strip-native-commands',
            "--vm=server",
            "--compress=2",
            '--output', "${buildDir}/distribution/${project.name}/runtime"
    ]

    doLast{
        System.out.println("Application '${project.name}' packaged.")
        System.out.println(" -> location: ${buildDir}/distribution/${project.name}/")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've learned that the central maven distributed jna-5.5.0.jar is not a modular jar file and so does not include the module-info.class file in the default package.

When I try (as suggested elsewhere) to create a modular jar version by manually inserting the module-info.class (created by jdeps)

Everything links, but when running the shared library (com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib for my Mac OS) does not get loaded.

I get the error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib) not found in resource path ()

Comment: Watching this thread; much interested, how to make it work.